# Limiting scope of :not to a class

Tags: jquery

I want to get all `div`s within an existing `div` which do not belong to certain classes. I am doing this to hide some of the `div`s without actually turning off all the `div`s in the page.

The code below displays the current way, which i took from an existing script.

```
$("div:not(.filterList, .prodGrid, " + allSelected + ")").hide();
```

I would like to do something like, (Note the `div.prodGrid`)

```
$("div.prodGrid:not(.filterList, .prodGrid, " + allSelected + ")").hide();
```

So far i have not been successful.

Comment: sure, adding it to the post

Answer (score 3):

You need to use jquery's  not()  selecter method for that purpose like below:

```
$("div.prodGrid").not(".filterList, .prodGrid, " + allSelected).hide();
```

[not() selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Comment: This doesn't work :( Prodgrid cancels itself. I was able to resolve this like this

$( "div.prodGrid" ).children().hide();
$(allSelected).show();

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle for that. I'll work that out.